# Disable / Changing default keyboard shortcuts in iTerm2

Tags: iterm2

I know I can add key shortcuts to a profile or in general to iTerm2

But **can** I, and if so, **how** do I disable or change the default application keyboard shortcuts in iTerm2?

For example, I'd like to disable the command `⌘ W` for Closing the current pane / window.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done in 2 ways.

**Using `defaults` command:**

1. Run `defaults write com.googlecode.iterm2.plist NSUserKeyEquivalents -dict-add "Close" "\U0000"`. (`\U0000` means `NULL`)
2. Restart iTerm2.

To revert this run, `defaults write com.googlecode.iterm2.plist NSUserKeyEquivalents -dict-add "Close" -string "@W"`

**Using System Preferences:** (In this method, shortcut is changed, not removed.)

1. Go to Preferences -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts -> App Shortcuts.
2. Click + icon
3. In the popup, select Application as iTerm, Menu title as "Close" (exactly as in the iTerm menu) and set the needed shortcut.

Comment: Thanks Vignesh! -- What about shortcuts for copy mode? (Just in case, I asked that in [this other Q](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59204637/keybindings-for-copy-mode-in-iterm2))

Comment: Sry, i couldn't get any lead on that.